# obfuscate string value java android

Tags: java, android, string, proguard, obfuscation

After search I understand that the proguard can't obfuscate strings values,
I tried the char [] type but after decompiling I can see the content of variable. So is there a solution to obfuscate static string variables? I have an adresse (string) should be secret in my code after obfuscating.

the code after decompiling

```
public static final char[] f4516b;
....
 static {
    f4516b = new char[]{'h', 't', 't', 'p', ':', '/', '/', '1', '0', '0', '.', '1', '0', '.', '1', '0', '0', '.', '1', '0', '/'};
```

Comment: Why do you think people will decompile your program to see your url?

Comment: I use a web service so they can do anything with that address after decompile.. I need to hide that string

Comment: @nouha I get that, but ofuscating the string in the source won't help much. On a rooted device or emulator it is easy to monitor all network traffic and find the ip/hostname anyway. 
Why do you think anyone could do anything with the address they can't do with the app / why is this a problem?

Comment: @Gumbo i use retrofit library for the webservice so i have some thing like that in my source code  `@GET("/api/stock")` , and my adresse https://..... is shown, so anybody can acess to this URL, so i should obfuscate strings values in my source code

Comment: @nouha I get that, but the information you have at that url is either publicly available through the app anyway or requires authentification to view, in either case it is no problem if people try to access it directly. Either way hiding the url in source is pointless, if i wanted to get it i would try wireshark first anyway.

Comment: @Gumbo yes your are right, so what i can do in this situation? there is a proposal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way you can keep some kind of offline secret inside an application. If you need it for your application to work at some point, it is automatically possible to reverse engineer it - otherwise your application would also lack the needed information.

Answer (score 1):

You can always create an de-obfuscation method, like a hash or a salt and keep the obfuscated string in a static variable. So the string will not be seen when decompiling.

But if the person use the de-obfuscation method they will have your string. Also, the remote call address will always be available if they listen the outgoing web call with wireshark or something alike.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, can you help me for the de-obfuscation? Just an example, or is there sothe solution?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make much sense to hide the url. It can be seen on the network layer. If you want to stop someone from accessing your website you can use for example the Basic authentication over HTTPS and hide the secrets using Android NDK (just an example). It can still be decompiled but it might be significantly harder.

Comment: Thanks for reply, can I see an example of your solution? I don't know this   , how to hide the secrets using Androi NDK? Can you explain plz ?